# Smoothness & performance issues of new game

Tags: java, performance, game-loop, frame-rate

I've written the basics of a new game which just includes a game loop that can update and render basic game objects so far.

I want to ensure that what I've written so far is as good as it can be and provides me with the best & most flexible foundation to build a game on top of. Really don't want to discover something fundamental later which causes a massive re-write.

Even though the game is running at a very decent frame rate the game objects are not moving entirely smoothly. I'm seeing stuttering and what looks like skipped frames, especially when the game objects bounce off the walls.

I'm not sure if this is a problem with my game loop or how I'm updating the game objects, or something else?!

If I increase the number of game objects from 5 to 100 the performance does not seem to change so I don't think it's a processing issue.

The project is only small at the moment - https://github.com/arrwhidev/java2d

Comment: You should run a profiler on your code and see where the issue lies.

Comment: You are using JFrames.  You are only rendering via CPU.  You should consider using a Game Engine instead.  What you are doing was not designed for fast paced games.

Comment: @Jon Don't think that's right. Java 2D calls have a hardware accelerated pipeline of some sort, what really matters is if he uses the correct Java 2D calls that are accelerated, and if not, takes the right steps to effectively make them so (like throw the graphics onto an image).

Comment: Learn OpenGL or DirectX or Vulkan. Seriously, Java Swing is as old as the wheel, and slower than [insert equally applicable comparison here]. Drop everything you're doing right now and learn one of those three.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your code, and there's one big performance issue that can lower your expected FPS.

It's that you are drawing to an image, which you then draw onto your `BufferStrategy`. Even though it's the same image object every render, this image is not going to be cached in VRAM because you keep changing it on every frame update. This means all your Java 2D calls against it are CPU bound. If you instead draw to your `BufferStrategy` graphics object then your Java 2D calls are translated for some hardware accelerated pipeline (most likely translated into OpenGL calls).

Using images is ok, just use them for static textures. An image should be cached in VRAM rather fast if you do not modify it (and of course also use it).

So change your code roughly to enable the following:

```
if (shouldRender) {
   frames++;
   render(bs.getDrawGraphics()); // render directly to the bufferstrategy
}
```